# Html5 Canvas - drawing perfect lines using fabric.js or without

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am creating a game, I need to achieve a perfect canvas line on HTML5 under different types of screen resolutions and zooms.

To easily understand I am talking about, simply paste the two different codes into an HTML file(not jsFiddle, as it is too small to notice):

With fabric.js:

```
<canvas id = "c" width = "600" height = "300"></canvas>
<script src = "https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>

<script> var c=document.getElementById("c");
 var context=c.getContext("2d");
 new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });
 context.moveTo(0, 0);
 context.lineTo(0, 300);
 context.stroke();
</script>
```

Without fabric.js:

```
<canvas id = "c" width = "600" height = "300"></canvas>
<script> var c=document.getElementById("c");
 var context=c.getContext("2d");
 context.moveTo(0, 0);
 context.lineTo(0, 300);
 context.stroke();
</script>
```

Now as you can see, fabric.js removes the blurriness that you get under different kind of browser zooms(Mouse wheel) once the page loads.
I have two problems with it though:

1) Once you click on the canvas the line is gone
2) It's a big framework/library, and I only need it to draw lines(Maybe not if it can achieve the same thing with PNG images)

So, is there a way to achieve the same sharpness result with a clean, short javascript code, without using fabric.js?
If not, how can I fix the clicking problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All lines drawn on the canvas are automatically given anti-aliasing to lessen the visual effect of "jaggies". This anti-aliasing also makes the line appear blurry.

If you ONLY are drawing horizontal and vertical lines you can make them crisp:

- Before drawing the lines, `context.translate(0.50,0.50)`,
- Draw the lines using only integer coordinates,
- After drawing the lines, `context.translate(-0.50,-0.50)`,

If you are drawing non-horizontal and non-vertical lines, then you can use [Bresenhan's Line Algorithm](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/group/goa/mallinnus/lines/bresenh.html) to draw crisp lines on the canvas by drawing lines pixel-by-pixel. This previous [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36211616/how-can-i-draw-a-diagonal-line-in-canvas-that-looks-the-same-in-safari-chrome/36212034#36212034) has example code using Bresenhan's algorithm.